# How to get all the inline images CID values from IMAP using coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, gmail, imap, email-attachments, gmail-imap

In my scenario, I've sent a mail with the pasted image in Gmail. I've put a dump to get the IMAP all emails list. That mail has displayed and the pasted image considered as an attachment. The attachment named as `image.png`. So that images CID will display in the cids column. Here when I pasted two images then the cids column display only the second added image's cid value. Because here the both pasted images named as `image.png`.

If I attach the file means that will working fine. The attachment filename have the original file name `jellyfish-Copy5.jpg`. so that is displaying the proper cid. I've added the dump details as image.

Email message with single Pasted Image:

[image]

Email message with Multiple Pasted Images:

[image]

Email message with Both Pasted and Attached Images:

[image]

So that How can I get both pasted images CID values from the query or what I want to do display both values into the cids column? Please guide me on this to get the CID values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of cfimap if the mail body have more than embedded images then it will take the last embedded image's CID.

`If the e-mail message contains more than one embedded image, only the last embedded image is available.`

Please refer it here https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfimap.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I should update me a bit more on cfimap related things.

Comment: FYI: We can get the all the images CID values from the imap htmlbody by using coldfusion functions.